# Как правильно: везти к, по или на место?

Tags: выбор-слов

...везти к(на, по) месту назначения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Я **предполагаю**, что употребление предлогов ***К, ПО, НА***  в подобных сочетаниях зависит **от следующих факторов**: (1) ехать/везти или отправить; (2) совершенный или несовершенный вид.

Ехать к месту назначения, приехать по месту назначения, приехать на место назначения.

Везти к месту назначения, привезти по месту назначения, привезти на место назначения.

Отправить по месту назначения, доставить по месту назначения, доставить на место назначения.

2) Мне кажется корректным следующее сочетание: ***Я вёз груз к месту назначения.***

3) **Другие сочетания вызывают сомнение:**

*Я вёз груз по месту назначения.* Сочетание *вёз по месту* напоминает сочетание *вёз по мосту* (по чему?)

*Я вёз груз на место назначения.* В принципе можно везти груз на вокзал, на стройку, но это конкретные объекты.

В приведенном предложении, когда объект имеет обобщенное название, выраженное словосочетанием, **направленность незаконченного движения** **лучше** обозначить предлогом К, чем предлогом НА.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о конечной точке, то следует употреблять  "в":

"новобранцев везли в часть".

Если доставка осуществляется не в само указанное место, а в его окрестность, надо ставить "к":

"лес для сплава везли к реке".

Если речь идёт о назначении и содержит информацию о последующем действии, то нужно писать "на":

"лом везли на переплавку", "пациента везли на операцию".

Если подчёркивается, по какой местности или каким транспортом осуществлялась доставка, используем "по":

"везли его гатью, по болоту" или "везли по мосту", "везли по железной дороге".

Comment: Интересная попытка (пусть даже она вызывает сомнения), но всё же Вы не ответили на вопрос.